# Linux Opensuse Network Manager service is not running - OPENSSL_1_1_1d not found

Tags: linux, wifi, opensuse, networkmanager, kde-plasma

I installed updates on my HP Opensuse Laptop and I cannot get wifi to connect anymore. The Wifi menu in the system tray is missing. I can see bluetooth, but not wifi. Upon investigation, Network Manager service is not running. When I try to run Networkmanager service from terminal using command `NetworkManager --no-daemon`, it comes up with the below error message.

`NetworkManager: /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1: version 'OPENSSL_1_1_1d' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4)`

I have done some research and tried the following things.

1. Disable NetworkManager and Enable wicked service, but still the interfaces are complaining about NM not working.
2. When I check `hwinfo`, I can see the correct model and drivers for the wlan adapter.
3. I enabled the disabled adapters using `ifup wlo1` as the interface was down when I checked `ip addr`
4. I was able to use `iwlist wlo1 scan`, I can see the networks in range, so the adapter is fine. It is an intel
5. I checked for bugs and there are some reports of similar behavior in 2019.
6. Use nmcli, it comes up with a message that "network manager is not running"
7. Tried to use YasT to disable NM and enable Wicked, but YasT does not bring up the `Network` screen any more after the update. It just spins and does nothing.
8. Ran Yast from terminal, it comes up with another message to report bug

```
Internal Error: Please report the bug report with logs. Run save_y2logs to get complete logs. 
Caller: /uwr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.6/0/yast/yast.rb:186:in "import_pure". 

Details: Failed to import module 'PackageSystem' due to component cannot import namespace 'pkg'
```

Configuration:

```
uname -a
Linux linux-new 5.4.7-1-default #1 SMP Wed jan 1 07:55:50 UTC 2020 (34ebd01)

cat /etc/*release
LSB_VERSION="core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64::core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64"
NAME="Opensuse Tumbleweed"
VERSION="20200110"
```

Does anyone have any ideas?